# Keras Conv. and Unconv. difference

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Conv2D 64-> 128 filters** has more weigths than **Conv2D 128-> 64 filters**. Why ?                                                                                                          .                                                                                           .

Thats the example Code of a UNET / CAE without skip or concatenations.

```
 Model: "model_29"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_756 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_757 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_120 (MaxPoolin (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_758 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_759 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_121 (MaxPoolin (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_760 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 256)         295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_761 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_106 (UpSamplin (None, 16, 16, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_762 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 128)       295040    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_763 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_107 (UpSamplin (None, 32, 32, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_764 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_765 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_108 (UpSamplin (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_766 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Some examples:**

```
32   =    18496  -  18464    (conv2d_756 (Conv2D) vs conv2d_766 (Conv2D))
64   =    73856  -  73792    (conv2d_758 (Conv2D) vs conv2d_764 (Conv2D))
128  =    295168 -  295040 (conv2d_760 (Conv2D) vs conv2d_762 (Conv2D))
```

Comment: 64 -> 128 has 128 bias terms. 128 -> 64 has 64 bias terms. Makes a difference of 64. That's it.

Comment: Yeah would make sense, but in the model.summary(), there is no "untrainable weigths" and normally, bias is untrainable -> because always 1, or isnt it ?

Comment: Ah never mind, you are rigth, its the bias terms...